# Organic reaction with Na2S2O4

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, organic-reduction, organic-oxidation

**Question:**

> [image]

In the first step due to cooperating Inductive and resonance effect C6H5N2 + will be attached at the ortho position of methyl group  for which para position is occupied by Amine group  but I am confused with the second reaction with  Na2S2O4.

Comment: Thanku that means C6h5N-  is separated and remaing =N got 2 hydrogen as a process of reduction the pdf is not opening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sodium dithionite Na2S2O4 (also called sodium hydrosulfite) is a flexible reducing agent that reduces and cleaves ArN=NAr bonds to give ArNH2. It is also good for ArNO2 to ArNH2 and reductions of enones to ketones. Further reading here [1](http://reag.paperplane.io/00002516.htm)

Comment: Thanku that means C6h5N-  is separated and remaing =N got 2 hydrogen as a process of reduction           am i correct in understandingthis way and           the pdf is not opening

Comment: You are correct - the other product is aniline. If you are happy with the answer please accept it. PDF should open now

Comment: You are correct. Both nitrogens from the N=N system end up with 2 hydrogens so the reaction product is D and aniline (C6H5NH2)

Comment: When we are going to add C6H5 N2+to the ring it gets add upto that postion otho to methyl grp bcoz    1 ) +M effect of NH2 is equally activating at both ortho and para postion but position ortho to nh2 would lead to decrease in activating affect of +I by CH3 grp so i thought the position ortho to Ch3 is decided in this way.... pls correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: The directing effect of the -NH2 is stronger than than the effect of the Me group, structure C is never going to be formed as it requires meta addition. Structure D is the only possible answer. Other isomers may be formed but that is beyond the scope of the question, addition to the 2 sides ortho to the NH2 is possible.